# Is there an easier way of chaining different jQuery actions for different selectors then nested $.when?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In jQuery you can [chain](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) actions for the same selector very easily but if you want to use different selector for each action it requires nested `$.when` with more then two actions which is quite hard to read and maintain.

HTML:

```
<span id='a'>Hello</span>
<span id='b'>world</span>
<span id='c'>!!!</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display: none;
}
```

JS: based on this: [how to hide multiple items but only call the handler once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226069/3449620)

```
var d = 500; // duration

// Execute in parallel.
//$('#a').show(d).hide(d);
//$('#b').show(d).hide(d);
//$('#c').show(d).hide(d);


$.when($('#a').fadeIn(d).fadeOut(d)).done(function () {
    $.when($('#b').show(d).hide(d)).done(function () {
        $('#c').slideDown(d).slideUp(d);
    });
});
```

*[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n63mk11/) (old)*

[jsfiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/3n63mk11/2/)

I thougt I could use the [queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) but it seems to work only for the same selector.

Is there a way to write it in a more maintainable manner like:

*pseudocode*

```
var myActions = [];
myActions.push(function(){...});
myActions.push(function(){...});
myActions.push(function(){...});
something.executeSequentially(myActions);
```

EDIT:

I updated the demo so that it's a little bit harder.

Comment: You could prototype your `executeSequentially` function, however the logic in that function would be exactly the same as your nested `$.when` calls, except it would be recursive. There is no way of doing what you ask in standard jQuery.

Comment: Argh, somehow I missed that `JS` tag making my vote the decisive one. ) Still think it's a pretty good duplicate - and [this particular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18979494/1229023) is especially nice for your `executeInSequence` functionality.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I saw the other question about chaining animations of which this might be a duplicate. Although I use fadeIn fadeOut in my example it is only for demonstration purpose. In my real code I have different actions that are not animations (hiding, changing attribute values etc.) so I decided to ask a new question because I didn't know how to chain them in an easy way.

Comment: What about somethin like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3n63mk11/1/

Comment: @dfsq: in theory it's a nice solution but I need different action for each selector... I my real code I'd like to hide the first one, show the other one, to the thrid one I'd like to add a class... I need to call a different action for each selector. Now when I think of it, it probably could be done recursively however I don't know how to call those actions on each selector.

Comment: Something like this: `myActions.push({selector: '#b', action: function(){...}});`

Comment: What about [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/g0ctLedb/) then?

Comment: @raina77ow that's exacly what I was looking for. I've just tested it with different actions http://jsfiddle.net/g0ctLedb/1/ and it works pefectly. Both the `reduce` and `promise` methods are new to me so I'll look into the docs next. I like the `return` inside each function, it's a nice trick so that they do not execute immediately. I hope the question get's reopend again and you'll get your credit for the solution :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really don't have to encounter for failures (and that's hardly possible with animations I suppose), you can use the following approach (kudos to @Esailija, as this solution is basically a simplified version of [*his answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979494/1229023)):

```
var chainOfActions = [
    function() { return $('#a').fadeIn(d).fadeOut(d); },
    function() { return $('#b').fadeIn(d).fadeOut(d); },
    function() { return $('#c').fadeIn(d).fadeOut(d); },
];
chainOfActions.reduce(function(curr, next) {
    return curr.then(next);
}, $().promise());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k9waxsr9/). There are three key points here:

- each function in chain of actions already returns a promise (if not, you can 'promisify' it with returning the result of `.promise()` call instead)
- at each step of `reduce` a chain is created, as each callback supplied into `then()` creates a new promise
- the whole chain is initiated by supplying an empty promise as the initial value of `reduce` accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

```
var d = 500
, something = {}
, myActions = [];

myActions.push(
function (next) {
    $('#a').fadeIn(d).fadeOut(d, next)
});
myActions.push(
function (next) {
    return $('#b').show(d).hide(d, next)
});
myActions.push(
function () {
    return $('#c').slideDown(d).slideUp(d)
});

something.executeSequentially = function (arr) {
    return $(this).queue("fx", arr);
};
something.executeSequentially(myActions);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/2oawa1zn/