# Why the callback in javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I want to call the second function after first is completed

```
function first(callback) {
     alert('called first');
     $('.fillColor1').animate({
         height: '50px'
     }, 600);
 }

function second() {
    alert('called second');
    $('.fillColor2').animate({
        height: '50px'
    }, 600);
}

$('button').click(function() {
    first(second);    
});
```

[Here is the code what i want on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aman0js/zqgfz54b/)

I got this problem then i searched for this and landed to this link

[Execute jquery function after another function completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674380/execute-jquery-function-after-another-function-completes)

Please let me know, is any mistake am i doing

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not using `callback` in your `first` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, Updated

```
function first(callback) {
     alert('called first');
     $('.fillColor1').animate({
         height: '50px'
     }, 600, callback);
}

function second() {
    alert('called second');
    $('.fillColor2').animate({
         height: '50px'
     }, 600);
}

$('button').click(function() {
    first(second);    
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zqgfz54b/1/

Alternatively

```
function fx(elem, callback) {
     alert('called ' + elem[0]);
     $('.fillColor' + elem[0])
     .animate({
         height: '50px'
     }, 600, function() {
       elem.splice(0, 1);
       callback.call($, elem)
     });
};

$('button').click(function() {
    fx.call($, [1, 2], fx);    
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zqgfz54b/2/

Comment: what should i do if i want to call series of functions similarly one after another ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Aman See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206855/is-there-an-easier-way-of-chaining-different-jquery-actions-for-different-select/27216737#27216737

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually call the callback after the first function:

```
function first(callback) {
     alert('called first');
     $('.fillColor1').animate({
         height: '50px'
     }, 600, callback);
}

function second() {
    alert('called second');
   //Do Code
}

$('button').click(function() {
    first(second);    
});
```

Comment: but by using this both function is being called at the same time i want to all the second one after first is completed

Comment: The jQuery animate method takes in a callback so you pass in the callback